# Is it possible pack a modern frontend web project source code into a single html file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web, webpack

I'm write a html test report generator. I want to embed all assets into a single html file. In this way, user can easily send it to others. All data will be written into this file when generating. User can double click it to open with a browser.

Since this html report is basically a template view with data bindings and user interaction. I'd like to use angularjs 2.0(+typescript) to implement it. And in order to use some beautiful grid/table, I probably need reference many external js libs.

I had checked [grunt-line](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-inline), it cannot deal with module loaders(eg. [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs))

**So, is there any way to achieve my goal?**

Comment: *All* assets? So you'll embed any images as `data:` URIs?

Comment: Check out http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/AssetsPack-a-friend-of-the-front-end-developer-node-nodejs-module-compilation-packing-minify maybe?

Comment: If your 'assets' are being sent as a JSON object you can just do a `<div *ngFor="asset in assets"></div>` maybe? As far as grid/tables you can use `ng2-material`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Assets can include fonts ("embedded" in this case would mean a link to the font file, which would have to be downloaded separately). Same with a video and images - you would not be able to include the raw data in an understandable way in HTML. Is your goal to create a package to demo all assets, like a UI library reference or style guide? Or when you send this file, do you intend to send JUST an html file, with no folder for links and assets referenced in the HTML?

Comment: @nnnnnn according to https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-inline, the images can be embedded as bas464 data

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly, you can try to use [gulp-inline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inline) or specific inlining tools like [gulp-inline-source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inline-source) for scripts, [gulp-inline-base64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inline-base64) for embedding fonts and images to styles and then [gulp-inline-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inline-css) for inlining the styles to html. There may be some other similar plugins.

---

## Example

https://github.com/artptr/html-inline-all-example

Assume that we write our application using Pug (formerly Jade), SASS, and LiveScript (that's all just for syntax consistency). And we have such structure:

```
- src/
  +- img/
     +- paragraph.png

  +- pug/
     +- index.pug

  +- live/
     +- script.ls

  +- sass/
     +- styles.sass

- tmp/    # for intermediate files

- dist/   # for result files

- gulpfile.js
- package.json
```

**package.json**

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-inline-source": "2.1.0",
    "gulp-livescript": "3.0.1",
    "gulp-postcss": "6.1.1",
    "gulp-pug": "3.0.3",
    "gulp-sass": "2.3.2",
    "livescript": "1.5.0",
    "postcss-url": "5.1.2"
  }
}
```

**src/sass/styles.sass**

Note that [postcss-url](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-url) will inline all external entities if there isn't any filter. Also there are similar plugins like [postcss-image-inliner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-image-inliner).

```
h1
  color: #c00;

  &:before
    content: ''
    display: inline-block
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background: url('../img/paragraph.png')
```

**src/live/script.ls**

That's just for example.

```
console.log 'Hello World'
```

**src/pug/index.pug**

Note that only tags with `inline` attribute (by default) will be processed for inlining as it's provided by [inline-source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inline-source). Also in this example there are hard links to the `tmp/` directory. You may use something like [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace) to prettify your sources.

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title All-Inlined HTML
    meta(charset="utf-8")
    link(href="../../tmp/css/styles.css", inline)
  body
    h1 All-Inlined HTML
    script(src="../../tmp/js/script.js", inline)
```

**gulpfile.js**

You may process your styles and scripts as you wish. For example you may use browserify, webpack, etc. Just process them into the right place.

```
const gulp         = require('gulp');
const sass         = require('gulp-sass');
const postcss      = require('gulp-postcss');
const url          = require('postcss-url');
const livescript   = require('gulp-livescript');
const pug          = require('gulp-pug');
const inlineSource = require('gulp-inline-source');

gulp.task('css', () =>
  gulp.src('./src/sass/*')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(postcss([
      url({ url: 'inline' }),  // inline images and fonts
    ]))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./tmp/css/'))
);

gulp.task('js', () =>
  gulp.src('./src/live/*')
    .pipe(livescript())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./tmp/js/'))
);

gulp.task('default', ['css', 'js'], () =>
  gulp.src('./src/pug/*')
    .pipe(pug())
    .pipe(inlineSource())  // inline scripts and styles
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
);
```

Finally there will be such output:

**dist/index.html**

(wrapped for readability)

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>All-Inlined HTML</title><meta charset="utf-8">
<style>h1{color:#c00}h1:before{content:'';display:inline-block;width:16px;height:16px;
background:url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAMAAAAoLQ9TAAAAA
3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAACXBIWXMAAAC0AAAAtAHrlyx7AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQB3d3cuaW5rc2NhcGUub3Jn
m+48GgAAAE5QTFRF////AKr/K4D/JJL/IID/KIf/JIr/JIf/JYn/I4j/JYn/JIj/JYf/JIj/JIj/JIj/JYj/JIn
/JIn/JIj/JIj/JIj/JIj/JIj/JIj/JIj/Ww11PAAAABl0Uk5TAAMGBwggP0BFSVJchJadocPExsjJ0PT3+B9r7C
0AAABTSURBVBhXtc1JDoAgAEPRrzigOANq739RN6Ihru3ypWkB3LrrTgQY9SYCnc6hNkHWKpgSmDQDXm0rD8CiP
odPI200CdLL0wC3HTlAUYUcstEf4AI8dAntxZ0PeQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==")}</style></head>
<body><h1>All-Inlined HTML</h1><script>(function(){console.log("Hello World")}).call(this);
</script></body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, I tried gulp-inline. But it cannot deal with imported js module via SystemJS

Comment: You can replace SystemJS with Webpack.

Comment: In order to make your answer even better, can you please post the code snippets, not just the raw references? thank you.

Comment: @Farside thank you for the suggest. I made an example.